# BeautifulSoup to find a HTML tag that contains tags with specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

How to find all tags that include tags with certain class?
The data is:

```
<tr>
<td class="TDo1" width=17%>Tournament</td>
<td class="TDo2" width=8%>Date</td>
<td class="TDo2" width=6%>Pts.</td>
<td class="TDo2" width=34%>Pos. Player (team)</td>
<td class="TDo5" width=35%>Pos. Opponent (team)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class=TDq1><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op)&nbsp;4.01/02</a></td>
<td class=TDq2><a href="p.pl?t=410&r=4">17.02.02</a></td>
<td class=TDq3>34/75</td>
<td class=TDq5>39. John Deep</td>
<td class=TDq9>68. <a href="p.pl?ply=1229">Mark Deep</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class=TDp1><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op)&nbsp;4.01/02</a></td>
<td class=TDp2><a href="p.pl?t=410&r=4">17.02.02</a></td>
<td class=TDp3>34/75</td>
<td class=TDp6>39. John Deep</td>
<td class=TDp8>7. <a href="p.pl?ply=10">Darius Star</a></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying

```
for mtable in bs.find_all('tr', text=re.compile(r'class=TD?3')):
print(mtable)
```

but this returns zero results.

Comment: `text()` is what's between the `<td ...>` and the `</td>`. You want `@class` I think... if this is XPath syntax

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to find all `<tr>` that contains any tag with class `TD<any character>3`:

```py
import re

# `html` contains your html from the question
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
pat = re.compile(r"TD.3")

for tr in soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "tr"
    and tag.find(class_=lambda cl: cl and pat.match(cl))
):
    print(tr)
```

Prints:

```html
<tr>
<td class="TDq1"><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op) 4.01/02</a></td>
<td class="TDq2"><a href="p.pl?t=410&amp;r=4">17.02.02</a></td>
<td class="TDq3">34/75</td>
<td class="TDq5">39. John Deep</td>
<td class="TDq9">68. <a href="p.pl?ply=1229">Mark Deep</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TDp1"><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op) 4.01/02</a></td>
<td class="TDp2"><a href="p.pl?t=410&amp;r=4">17.02.02</a></td>
<td class="TDp3">34/75</td>
<td class="TDp6">39. John Deep</td>
<td class="TDp8">7. <a href="p.pl?ply=10">Darius Star</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That is the best solution because I need insert data from that group of TD insert in single record in DB. Thanks

Comment: And how to extract each TD into element of a record:
["p.pl?t=410", GpWl(op), 4.01/02, "p.pl?t=410&amp;r=4", 17.02.02, 34/75, "TDp6", 39, John Deep ...]
TDP6 is when John Deep is loser and TDP5 is when John Deep is winner

Answer (score 0):

You need to find matching with `td`. Like this,

```
In [1]: bs.find_all('td', {"class": re.compile(r'TD\w\d')})
Out[1]: 
[<td class="TDo1" width="17%">Tournament</td>,
 <td class="TDo2" width="8%">Date</td>,
 <td class="TDo2" width="6%">Pts.</td>,
 <td class="TDo2" width="34%">Pos. Player (team)</td>,
 <td class="TDo5" width="35%">Pos. Opponent (team)</td>,
 <td class="TDq1"><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op) 4.01/02</a></td>,
 <td class="TDq2"><a href="p.pl?t=410&amp;r=4">17.02.02</a></td>,
 <td class="TDq3">34/75</td>,
 <td class="TDq5">39. John Deep</td>,
 <td class="TDq9">68. <a href="p.pl?ply=1229">Mark Deep</a></td>,
 <td class="TDp1"><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op) 4.01/02</a></td>,
 <td class="TDp2"><a href="p.pl?t=410&amp;r=4">17.02.02</a></td>,
 <td class="TDp3">34/75</td>,
 <td class="TDp6">39. John Deep</td>,
 <td class="TDp8">7. <a href="p.pl?ply=10">Darius Star</a></td>]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

t = 'your page source' 
pat = re.compile(r'class=TD.3')
classes = re.findall(pat,t)
classes = [j[6:] for j in classes]
soup = BeautifulSoup(t)
result = list()
for i in classes:
    item = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": i})
    result.extend(item)
for i in result:
    print(i.parent)
```

Comment: {NameError}name 'mtable' is not defined in re.py

Answer (score 0):

You could use [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to get the tags with `class = "TD...3"` and then get their parent tags

```py
mtables = [s.parent for s in bs.select('*[class^="TD"][class$="3"]')]

# if you want tr only:
# mtables = [s.parent for s in bs.select('tr *[class^="TD"][class$="3"]')]

mtables = list(set(mtables)) # no duplicates
```

but this will not work if there are multiple classes (unless the first one starts with "TD" and the last ends in "3"), and you can't limit the characters in between.

---

You could use `find` with `lambda` twice like this

```py
tagPat = '^TD.3$' 
# tagPat = '^TD.*3$' # if there might be more than one character between TD and 3
mtables = bs.find_all(
  lambda p: 
  p.name == 'tr' and # remove if you want all tags and not just tr
  p.find(
    lambda t: t.get('class') is not None and 
    len([c for c in t.get('class') if re.search('^TD.3$', c)]) > 0
    , recursive=False # prevent getting <tr><tr><td class="TDo3">someval</td></tr></tr>
  ))
```

---

If you don't want to use `lambda`, you can replace the `select` in the first method with regex and `find`

```py
tagPat = '^TD.3$' # '^TD.*3$' #
mtables = [
    s.parent for s in bs.find_all(class_ = re.compile(tagPat))
    if s.parent.name == 'tr' # remove if you want all tags and not just tr
]
mtables = list(set(mtables)) # no duplicates
```

---

---

For the html in your question all 3 methods would lead to same data - you can print with

```py
for mtable in mtables: print('---\n', mtable, '\n---')
```

and get the output

```html
---
 <tr>
<td class="TDq1"><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op) 4.01/02</a></td>
<td class="TDq2"><a href="p.pl?t=410&amp;r=4">17.02.02</a></td>
<td class="TDq3">34/75</td>
<td class="TDq5">39. John Deep</td>
<td class="TDq9">68. <a href="p.pl?ply=1229">Mark Deep</a></td>
</tr> 
---
---
 <tr>
<td class="TDp1"><a href="p.pl?t=410">GpWl(op) 4.01/02</a></td>
<td class="TDp2"><a href="p.pl?t=410&amp;r=4">17.02.02</a></td>
<td class="TDp3">34/75</td>
<td class="TDp6">39. John Deep</td>
<td class="TDp8">7. <a href="p.pl?ply=10">Darius Star</a></td>
</tr> 
---
```